# How to make the overlay width and height fixed in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

for example

```
 // Common overlay image input
 String commonOverlayImage = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20230530_201349.jpg';

 // First execution
 String backgroundImage1 = 'storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20230530_201359.jpg'; // width: 2448, height: 3264
 String outputPath1 = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/outputPath1.jpg';
 String command1 = '-y -i $backgroundImage1 -i $commonOverlayImage -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:500[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=100:100" $outPutPath1';

 // Second execution
 String backgroundImage2 = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg'; // width: 736, height: 272
 String outputPath2 = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/outputPath2.jpg';
 String command2 = '-y -i $backgroundImage2 -i $commonOverlayImage -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:500[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=100:100" $outPutPath2';
```

the previous two executions work fine but the issue is commonOverlayImage look difference in width and height and position too , however they have the same values and this because the difference of `backgroundImage1` and `backgroundImage1` dimensions

How can i make them fixed and look the same always whatever `backgroundImage` dimensions is